# Properly pass Swift closure into another thread

Tags: swift, multithreading

How do I properly (from multithreading point of view) pass a closure to another thread?

Consider a situation:

```
class NetManager {
    ...
    var processingClosure : (Data, DispatchQueue, @escaping (Data?) -> ()) -> () = {
        respData, complQueue, complClosure in
        let resultData = // process respData according to some logic and get resultData
        complQueue.async {
            complClosure(resultData)
        }
        // PLEASE NOTE that there is no captured variables in this closure
    }
    ...
    func requestData1(..., complClosure) {
        // this is main thread context
        // make request to endpoint 1 somehow and process result in separate processing queue
        ...
        let procClosure = self.processingClosure
        // processingQueue is NOT main queue and not completion queue 
        request.processingQueue.async {
            // Question HERE:
            procClosure(data, DispatchQueue.main, complClosure)
            // is such passing of the closure safe? Can I have issues with concurrency?
        }
    }

    func requestData2(..., complClosure) {
        // the same as requestData1 but gets data from endpoint 2
        ...
        let procClosure = self.processingClosure
        request.processingQueue.async {
            procClosure(data, DispatchQueue.main, complClosure)
        }
    }
}
```

This seems a safe way to pass closure since it doesn't capture any variables. Will I have any concurrency issues with procClosure call?

Is there a better way to encapsulate a common functionality of data transformation to reuse in similar requests to different endpoints (I can encapsulate only data processing but not requesting)?

Comment: do you only want one of them to run ? this is obviously a race condition if both of them get called before one finishes. But if it matters which one gets called first or what not you can always just store a variable when procClosure gets called and always see if that variable has been set or not. Depending on if it has been you call procClosure.

Comment: @TPN1994 no, both requestData1 and requestData2 can run simultaneously. Although as I have written closure itself doesn't capture anything so I would say it should be reentrant. Before, in obj-c I would just copy closures(blocks) but it doesn't seem to be possible in Swift.

Comment: ah my mistkae, I understand the question better now. Just curious though, why do you need to pass a closure from one thread to another like that? Why do you need to have procClosure running on a specific thread?

Comment: @TPN1994 well, I have different endpoints with different request forming but the data processing is the same. It is relatively heavy so it is better to process it off the main thread. As there is no reason to write code multiple times, it needs to be encapsulated somewhere. One possibility is closure, another is global function.